# Numpy dot one matrix with an array of vectors and get a new array of vectors

Tags: python, numpy

Say we have an array of 2D vectors (describing a square shape), and a matrix (scale along y axis):

```
vecs = np.array([[1, 0],
                 [1, 1],
                 [0, 1],
                 [0, 0]])
mat = np.array([[1, 0],
                [0, 2]])
```

I want to get a new array of vectors, where each vector from `vecs` is dot multiplied with `mat`. Now I do it like this:

```
new_vecs = vecs.copy()
for i, vec in enumerate(vecs):
    new_vecs[i] = np.dot(mat, vec)
```

This produces the desired result:

```
>>> print(new_vecs)
[[1 0]
 [1 2]
 [0 2]
 [0 0]]
```

What are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot product `np.dot` will multiply matrices of any shape with each other, as long as their shapes line up: `np.dot((a,b), (b,c)) -> (a,c)`. So if you invert the order, Numpy does this for you in one call:

```
In [3]: np.dot(vecs, mat)
Out[3]:
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: `np.dot(vec, mat)` is not the same as `np.dot(mat, vec)` but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
np.dot(mat , vecs.T).T
```